# Заполнение и отправка электронной почты

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста! В чем ошибка этого PHP сценария? Все перепроверил, но не могу найти синтаксическую ошибку. 
Пытаюсь создать электр. форму для рассылки писем. При вводе текста она проверяет заполнена ли содержание и тема формы, если да то идет подключение к базе данных и отправка писем всем находящимся в базе данных клиентов, если нет, то отправка не производится.

Посмотрите:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title>Мой Мир</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$from = 'UFO@fang21.ru';
$subject = $_POST ['subject'];
$text = $_POST ['elvismail'];
$output_form = false;

if (empty($subject) && empty($text)) {
echo 'Вы забли ввести тему и содержание электроного письма.<br />';
$output_form = true;
}

if (empty($subject) && (!empty($text))) {
echo 'Вы забли ввести тему электроного письма.<br />';
$output_form = true;
}

if ((!empty($subject)) && empty($text)) {
echo 'Вы забли ввести содержание электроного письма.<br />';
$output_form = true;
}

if ((!empty($subject)) && (!empty($text))) {
//Все отлично, отправляем электронное письмо
$dbc = mysqli_connect ('localhost', '', '','r0058300_arty21')
   or die ('ошибка соединения с MySQL-сервером');

mysqli_set_charset($dbc, "cp1251");

$query = "SELECT * FROM email_list";
$result = mysqli_query( $dbc, $query)
or die ('ошибка при выполнении запроса к базе данных.');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$first_name = $row ['first_name'];
$last_name = $row ['last_name'];

$msg = " Уважаемый $first_name $last_name, \n $text ";
$to = $row ['email'];
mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From: ' . $from );
echo 'Электронное письмо отправлено: ' . $to . '<br />';
mysqli_close($dbc);

}
}

else {
$output_form = true;
}

if ($output_form)  {

?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">    
<label for="subject">Subject of email:</label><br />   
<input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>" 
<label for="elvismail">Body of email:</label><br />    
<textarea id="elvismail" name="elvismail" rows="8" cols="40"><?php echo $text; ?>
</textarea><br />   
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />  
</form>

<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Помогите разобраться!

Comment: А ошибку выдаёт интерпретатор или же вы сами так решили? Укажите строчку на которую ругается интерпретатор.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/r0058300/data/www/fang21.ru/sendemail.php on line 82  Вот так он ругается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не закрыта фигурная скобка вот от этой строчки

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Comment: А где она должна закрывать! Ведь по идеи она закрывает $msg = " Уважаемый $first_name $last_name, \n $text ";
$to = $row ['email'];
mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From: ' . $from );
echo 'Электронное письмо отправлено: ' . $to . '<br />';
mysqli_close($dbc);}    }-вот она закрывающая скобка. 

Может я ее не там установил?

Comment: эта скобка закрывает 

    if ((!empty($subject)) && (!empty($text))) {

возьмите какой-нибудь редактор с подсветкой и посмотрите сами. (я использую vim)

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста! Теперь он письма отправляет, но пишет что Warning: mysqli_close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /var/www/r0058300/data/www/.../sendemail.php on line 55? При этом первые два адреса из таблицы в базе данных он отправляет нормально. По идеи функция mysqli_close()должна закрывать соединение с базой данных.

Comment: @Arty21 будьте внимательны, вы закрываете соединение в блоке while, естественно оно не сможет закрыть соединение второй раз, fetch почему работает, я не знаю точно, но вынесите закрытие из блока *и выучите синтаксис*, так вы у меня каждый шаг спрашивать будете - это не программирование.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Извините что доставал вас по пустякам! И я по вашему совету скачал vim. Все вам наилучшего, и еще раз спасибо!